# C++: Program won't output as expected

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


void getJudgesData(double);
void calcScore(double, double, double, double, double, double);

int findLowest(double, double, double, double, double);
int findHighest(double, double, double, double, double);

double judgeOne, judgeTwo, judgeThree, judgeFour, judgeFive; // global vars

int main() {
    cout << "---------------------Star Search---------------------" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the 5 scores for the contestant and I will drop the lowest and highest to find the average score:" << endl;
    getJudgesData(judgeOne);
    getJudgesData(judgeTwo);
    getJudgesData(judgeThree);
    getJudgesData(judgeFour);
    getJudgesData(judgeFive);
    cout << "Average score: ";
    double outputCalc = 0;
    calcScore(judgeOne, judgeTwo, judgeThree, judgeFour, judgeFive, outputCalc);
    cout << outputCalc;
}

void getJudgesData(double judgeInput) {
    cout << endl << "Enter judge's score: ";
    cin >> judgeInput;
    while(judgeInput < 0 || judgeInput > 10){
        cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
        cin >> judgeInput;
    }
}

void calcScore(double inp1, double inp2, double inp3, double inp4, double inp5, double output) {
    output = 0;
    output = ((inp1 + inp2 + inp3 + inp4 + inp5) - findLowest(inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5) - findHighest(inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5)) / 3;
}

int findLowest(double int1, double int2, double int3, double int4, double int5) {
    return min({int1, int2, int3, int4, int5});
}

int findHighest(double int1, double int2, double int3, double int4, double int5) {
    return max({ int1, int2, int3, int4, int5 });
}
```

Here's the assignment:

"A particular talent completion has five judges, each of whom awards a score between 0 and 10 to each performer. Fractional scores, such as 8.3 are allowed. A performer’s score is determined by the highest and lowest score received, and then averaging the three remaining scores. This process may continue as long as the user wants to enter scores for another contestant. Write a program that uses this method to calculate a contestant’s score.

Include the following functions in your program:

Void getJudgesData() should ask the user for a judge’s score, store it in a reference parameter variable, and validate it. This function should be called by main once for each of the judges.
Void calcScore() should calculate and display the average of the three scores that remain after dropping the highest and lowest scores. This function should be called once in the main and you should pass 5 scores to it.

The following two functions should be called by calcScore, which uses the returned information to determine which of the scores to drop:

int findLowest() should find and return the lowest of the five scores passed to it.

int findHigest() should find and return the highest of five scores passed to it."

I can't figure out why it won't output the correct value, It compiles fine, but it always outputs zero as the average score. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Edit: The program works now! Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


void getJudgesData(double&);
void calcScore(double, double, double, double, double, double&);

int findLowest(double, double, double, double, double);
int findHighest(double, double, double, double, double);

double judgeOne, judgeTwo, judgeThree, judgeFour, judgeFive; // global vars

int main() {
    cout << "---------------------Star Search---------------------" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the 5 scores for the contestant and I will drop the lowest and highest to find the average score:" << endl;
    getJudgesData(judgeOne);
    getJudgesData(judgeTwo);
    getJudgesData(judgeThree);
    getJudgesData(judgeFour);
    getJudgesData(judgeFive);
    cout << "Average score: ";
    double outputCalc = 0;
    calcScore(judgeOne, judgeTwo, judgeThree, judgeFour, judgeFive, outputCalc);
    cout << outputCalc;
}

void getJudgesData(double& judgeInput) {
    cout << endl << "Enter judge's score: ";
    cin >> judgeInput;
    while(judgeInput < 0 || judgeInput > 10){
        cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
        cin >> judgeInput;
    }
}

void calcScore(double inp1, double inp2, double inp3, double inp4, double inp5, double& output) {
    output = 0;
    output = ((inp1 + inp2 + inp3 + inp4 + inp5) - findLowest(inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5) - findHighest(inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5)) / 3;
}

int findLowest(double int1, double int2, double int3, double int4, double int5) {
    return min({int1, int2, int3, int4, int5});
}

int findHighest(double int1, double int2, double int3, double int4, double int5) {
    return max({ int1, int2, int3, int4, int5 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program does not behave correctly because the double judgeOne is passed by value (copied) when you pass it as a formal parameter of a function.

in your case, when you pass in judgeOne to getJudgeData(), a copy of judgeOne value will get passed to getJudgeData() and whatever happens inside the function will not take effect.

an approach that will work:

you should have getJudgeData() have return type double, and assign like this:

```
judgeOne = getJudgeData(); //no need for argument
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the & in getJudgeData() helped resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reference if you want to read the modified value:

```
void calcScore(double inp1, double inp2, double inp3, double inp4, double inp5, double& output)
```

Otherwise the `output` parameter is passed by value and change is lost when you move out of scope.

Also the name selection is kind of... weird. `double int1`?

Comment: I'll fix the names of the variables, thanks for pointing that out. I tried including the & in both the function definition and prototype, but it still outputs 0.

Comment: Well, you need to debug here, I don't know what values have you provided. Try to start with two values. Also, as the other answer pointed out - get the value as a function return value is much better approach.

Comment: I'd like to make the function return value as the value I'm receiving, however the assignment limits me to keeping it a void function.

Comment: Oh, I see, so disregard the second part of comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help Roman!